# SocksPolicy accept * not work

Tags: proxy

I want to setup a tor proxy in a vmware virtual machine. So I can use that as a proxy on my host machine.

I set `SocksPolicy accept *` in torrc, but not work.

1. test in that vm machine,

   ```
   curl --socks5 localhost:9050 --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 -s https://check.torproject.org/ | cat | grep -m 1 Congratulations | xargs
   ```

   correct return
2. test on my host machine

   ```
   curl --socks5 192.168.126.143:9050 --socks5-hostname 192.168.126.143:9050 -s https://check.torproject.org/ | cat | grep -m 1 Congratulations | xargs
   ```

   hang

   ```
   $ nc -v 192.168.126.143 9050
   nc: connect to 192.168.126.143 port 9050 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
   ```

Answer (score 1):

At first, I think `SocksPolicy` control the listen address access.
But it need use `SocksPort` to bind address, which looks werid ...

Anyway, this setting can solve the problem

```
SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9050 
SocksPolicy accept *
```